# Regex PHP Decimal Number with point and operator

Tags: php, regex

I have a list and I want to retrieve all decimal numbers in it. They are stored like this +900.00 or -240.30.
They all have an operator "+" or "-".

```
$liste = "Pack Eclairage : Lave-phares Projecteurs Bi-X\u00e9non 35W directionnels Feux AV eclairage diurne LED : -400.00Etriers de freins Rouge : +200.00|Jantes en alliage 19\" Performance Noires (avec Pneus Run-On Flat) : +900.00|Pack Confort : Syst\u00e8me d'entr\u00e9e sans cl\u00e9s (conducteur et passager) Eclairage des poign\u00e9es de portes Compartiment porte-objets c\u00f4t\u00e9 conducteur Pare-soleil conducteur avec illumination : +580.00|Peinture Pastel Extra-s\u00e9rie Blanc Alfa : +650.00|Vitres AR privatives : +390.00";
$tab_liste = explode("|", $liste);

foreach($tab_liste as $option) {
    // regex here 
}
```

**EDIT :** 
How can I do in PHP to retrieve first the option name, second the operator and third the decimal number ? 
Thanks.

Comment: We've added some answers for you. Is that helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use `explode()` here, because `preg_match_all` can handle doing multiple regex matches across a given input string:

```
$liste = "Pack Eclairage : Lave-phares Projecteurs Bi-X\u00e9non 35W directionnels Feux AV eclairage diurne LED : -400.00Etriers de freins Rouge : +200.00|Jantes en alliage 19\" Performance Noires (avec Pneus Run-On Flat) : +900.00|Pack Confort : Syst\u00e8me d'entr\u00e9e sans cl\u00e9s (conducteur et passager) Eclairage des poign\u00e9es de portes Compartiment porte-objets c\u00f4t\u00e9 conducteur Pare-soleil conducteur avec illumination : +580.00|Peinture Pastel Extra-s\u00e9rie Blanc Alfa : +650.00|Vitres AR privatives : +390.00";
preg_match_all ("/([+\-])(\d+(\.\d+)?)/", $liste, $array);

for ($i=0; $i < count($array[1]); $i++) {
    echo $array[1][$i] . ", " . $array[2][$i] . "\n";
}

-, 400.00
+, 200.00
+, 900.00
+, 580.00
+, 650.00
+, 390.00
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can do with [regex](https://regex101.com/r/n7X2RP/1) `/[+-]\d+\.?\d*/m`

```
<?php
$re = '/[+-]\d+\.?\d*/m';
$str = 'Pack Eclairage : Lave-phares Projecteurs Bi-X\\u00e9non 35W directionnels Feux AV eclairage diurne LED : -400.00Etriers de freins Rouge : +200.00|Jantes en alliage 19\\" Performance Noires (avec Pneus Run-On Flat) : +900.00|Pack Confort : Syst\\u00e8me d\'entr\\u00e9e sans cl\\u00e9s (conducteur et passager) Eclairage des poign\\u00e9es de portes Compartiment porte-objets c\\u00f4t\\u00e9 conducteur Pare-soleil conducteur avec illumination : +580.00|Peinture Pastel Extra-s\\u00e9rie Blanc Alfa : +650.00|Vitres AR privatives : +390.00';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
// Print the entire match result
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$matches);
print_r($result);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array ( 
 [0] => -400.00 
 [1] => +200.00
 [2] => +900.00 
 [3] => +580.00 
 [4] => +650.00 
 [5] => +390.00
)
```

**DEMO** : https://3v4l.org/X2DK6

Answer (score 0):

```
    $liste = "Pack Eclairage : Lave-phares Projecteurs Bi-X\u00e9non 35W directionnels Feux AV eclairage diurne LED : -400.00Etriers de freins Rouge : +200.00|Jantes en alliage 19\" Performance Noires (avec Pneus Run-On Flat) : +900.00|Pack Confort : Syst\u00e8me d'entr\u00e9e sans cl\u00e9s (conducteur et passager) Eclairage des poign\u00e9es de portes Compartiment porte-objets c\u00f4t\u00e9 conducteur Pare-soleil conducteur avec illumination : +580.00|Peinture Pastel Extra-s\u00e9rie Blanc Alfa : +650.00|Vitres AR privatives : +390.00";
    $tab_liste = explode("|", $liste);

    foreach($tab_liste as $option) {
        preg_match_all("#((\-|\+)[\d\.]+)#", $option, $matches);
       var_dump($matches[0]);
       echo "<br>";
    }
```